# current_date usage

Tags: sql, jdbc

I would like to subtract the current date from a given date in SQL or in JDBC. I would like to have the result in hours. Not sure how to treat the date in that case. Can some one give me a basic example Please.

Comment: Everything you need is right here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html, but I am sure in a few minutes someone will post a code sample as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database server you use - here's a sample in MySQL.

```
select hour(TIMEDIFF('2011-03-15 19:59:59.000001', now()))
```

Note: the "hour" function doesn't deal with rounding, so if you need that, you need to do some further arithmetic.

Date functions are pretty vendor-specific, so your mileage may vary....

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL

```
select (date '2011-03-16' - CURRENT_DATE) as days_different,
       (date '2011-03-16' - CURRENT_DATE) * 24 as hours_different

days_different  hours_different
--
1               24
```

As I write this, CURRENT_DATE = '2011-03-15'.